# Inconsistent Results with Grep

Tags: regex, grep

I am grepping through some files look for the string 'host' (with the single quotes).  I want to  capture the files that have the string without a comment (#).

The test case in  the first example works just fine, but the 2nd case below does not.  The 2nd case is a test file that I created, and inserted leading spaces in.  So I know that there are no control characters, just whitespace.

Both servers are fairly recent versions of Linux.

What could account for the 2nd example not capturing the text?  I know I can just grep for **host**, and then filter with **grep -v** the comments, but it bugs me that I don't understand this.

```
/home/user2> $ cat set.txt
   'host'
/home/user2> $ grep -E "^\s+'host'" set.txt
   'host'
```

Grep on the other Linux server does not capture the desired data:

```
[user1@wweb1 ~]$ cat set.txt
     'host'  
[user1@wweb1 ~]$ grep -E "^\s+'host'" set.txt
[user1@wweb1 ~]$
```

Comment: maybe the commands are aliased on different grep flavours? can you check it?

Comment: Good question.  I ran "set" and "env" and nothing seems aliased.

Comment: `grep -V` report the same version for both grep command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on `grep` version and type, `\s` might not work. On my system with grep 2.12, there is no mention of `\s`, though it does work anyway. Other versions may not have this enabled.

From the man page:

```
The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
   The symbols \< and \>  respectively  match  the  empty  string  at  the
   beginning and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at
   the edge of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided  it's  not
   at the edge of a word.  The symbol \w is a synonym for [_[:alnum:]] and
   \W is a synonym for [^_[:alnum:]].
```

Additionally, `man grep | grep "\\\\s"` returns nothing at all. And that's it: no mention of `\s`.

Instead, you could use `[:space:]` as so:

```
 user@pc $ grep -E "^[[:space:]]+'host'" set.txt
     'host'
```

So check your grep versions, and go for the syntax that works in all of them. [This mailing list post](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-grep@gnu.org/msg02689.html) says `\s` did not work in grep 2.5.1, but did work in 2.6.3, so of you have a pre-2.6.3 version, it might not work with `\s`.

Comment: I can confirm that grep 2.5.1 does not work: `echo '  123' | grep -E '^\s+123'` gives no match, but `echo '  123' | grep -E '^\s\s*123'` matches. So it seems to be more of a "+" issue than a "\s" issue. Hmmm... my man page for grep also says that `\w` is a synonym for `[[:alnum:]]` and `\W` is a synonym for `[^[:alnum:]]` -- which is wrong. The version of grep is `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` on FreeBSD 11.4.